# Regex to get body of a raw RFC 822 formatted email

Tags: regex, pcre

```
Subject: test MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
         boundary"----_Part_1631742_816935001.1527406760596" References: <414671049.1631743.1527406760597.ref@mail.yahoo.com>
X-Mailer: WebService/1.1.11897 YMailNorrin Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36 Content-Length: 416

------_Part_1631742_816935001.1527406760596 Content-Type: text/plain; charsetUTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

test
------_Part_1631742_816935001.1527406760596 Content-Type: text/html; charsetUTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html><head></head><body><div style"font-family:lucida console,
sans-serif;font-size:24px;"><div>test</div></div></body></html>
------_Part_1631742_816935001.1527406760596--
```

I'm only trying to get the following snippet:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charsetUTF-8 

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

"test"

---
```

Basically anything between 7bit and three -'s.

I've tried the following regexes w/o success:
Regex #1: `Content-Type: text/plain;(.*)(\n\n)(.*)---`

I thought I'd be able to use capture groups to get the content, but I'm having all sorts of problems. I'm using a MacOS terminal and `pcre`.

Comment: I don't see the point of writing a regex for this.  Your starting/ending markers are the only distinct items which are present in what you want to capture.

Comment: Tim, could you explain further? How else would I do this?

Comment: I don't understand your criteria for matching, and it seems you might do just as well to match for the literal strings you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In PCRE a `.` doesn't include multiple lines. You need the single line modifier to have the `.` include them. Try adding `(?s)` to your regex, like this:

```
(?s)Content-Type: text/plain;(.*)(\n\n)(.*)---
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charsetUTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\s*([\s\S]*?)-{3}
```